# Laravel: Use case for File Visibility?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel with a local filesystem as storage driver.

I have understood that I can save files in the `storage/public` folder to make them accessible through `myapp.dev/storage/image.jpg`. I have also understood that I can make images accessible only for authenticated users like explained [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/image-accessibility-for-authenticated-users-only).

What I have not understood it the [File Visibility](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-visibility) property. If files are public depending on the folder that I stored them, why would I need to declare them additionally as `private` or `public`? Could anyone give a use case where this would be necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File visibility option matters only if you are using cloud storage provider, e.g. Amazon S3 or something like that. If you are working with local file system then that option is ignored.

Comment: "Ignored" is perhaps the wrong way to describe it. Files saved with public/private visiblity are given different read/write/execute permissions based on what is configured for the project. However, in many (the majority?) of server configurations both public and private settings may result in files being readable by the webserver and served to users, making it seem like the setting is ignored. One case where one might see a difference is if the webserver runs as the `www-data` user and php-fpm is run as its own user. Private files are 0600 permissions by default, so `www-data` can't read them.